# How to execute SQL script that creates stored procedure by using .NET Connector for MySQL

Tags: .net, stored-procedures, mysql-connector

I have created a simple WinForm application that needs to execute SQL scripts.
The result of the execution may be zero, one or more recordsets. Basically the following is done:

```
var ds = MySqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(Dsn, sqlString);
```

It works OK, but the problem arises when SQL script contains the code that should create a stored procedure. This works:

```
CREATE DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost'
PROCEDURE test1()
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM table_1;
END
```

However, when script contains one more statement, then I get an error.

```
CREATE DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost'
PROCEDURE test1()
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM table_1;
  SET @s1 = 'Any text...'; -- This is the problematic statement!
END
```

The error message is: "**Parameter '@s1' must be defined!**" 
Briefly, I don't want to provide parameter to the "**MySqlHelper.ExecuteDataset**" command. I want to create procedure that will contain 'SET @s1 = ...' statement.

How this can be solved?
Thanks.

Comment: I'm guessing you would first have to declare it:  `DECLARE @s1 NVARCHAR(50)` or something like that.

Comment: Error Message is not generated by MySql - it's not wrong syntax. It's generated by MySqlHelper class. Method 'ExecuteDataset' expect user parameters because of '@s1' variable, but I want just to create procedure code, not to pass a user parameter.